# <div> displays "0" instead of showing the appended result of a function - JQuery

Tags: jquery, append, checkboxlist

I have this html code:

```
 <form name="this form">
 <div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list">
    <div class="anchor">Everyone</div>
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="round"><input name="options" type="checkbox" value="round"/> round </li>
        <li class="blue"><input name="options" type="checkbox" value="orange"/>Orange</li>
        <li class="white"><input name="options"type="checkbox" value="grapes" />Grapes </li>

    </ul>
```

so far so good...now, I am trying to replace the "Everyone" inside the div(of class anchor) with a list of all the selected/checked items. this is my JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {


    function getSelected(opt) {
        var selected = new Array();
        var index = 0;
        for (var intLoop = 0; intLoop < opt.length; intLoop++) {
           if ((opt[intLoop].selected) ||
               (opt[intLoop].checked)) {
              index = selected.length;
              selected[index] = new Object;
              selected[index].value = opt[intLoop].value;
              selected[index].index = intLoop;
           }
        }
        return selected;
     }





           function outputSelected(opt) {
        var sel = getSelected(opt);
        var strSel = "";
        var count = sel.length;
        var Ocount = opt.length;
        var Text = "";
        for (var item in sel)     
                {strSel += sel[item].value + "; "; }

         if (count == 0)
                { Text = "none";}
         else if (count == Ocount)
                { Text= "Everybody";}
         else
                {Text = strSel;}


          };

          $("div.anchor").empty().append(Text);

          });
```

To my utter bewilderment, the text in the div turns into "0" instead of any of the options i was trying to give it...I checked all my variables by doing alert(strSel+" "+count+" "+Ocount); and they're all displaying the right values(strSel displays the list of selected items, separated by ";"s). Why is it not working?

Comment: What calls your functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I haven an idea of what you're trying to do. Unfortunately, I can't answer your question since you're missing a few things from your question (how your elements are binded, for instance) - in addition, there's some syntax issues with your code (missing brackets, invalid conditions, etc.)

One thing I would recommend though, is take advantage of jQuery a bit more - it has a ton of helper functions and selector support that makes our lives much easier! You could simplify your code by doing something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e){
        var str = '';
        var total = $('.items input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var checked = $('.items :checked').length;

        if($('.items :checked').length === 0) {
            str = 'None';   
        } else {
            if(checked === total) {
                str = 'Everybody';   
            } else {
                $('.items :checked').each(function(){
                    str += $(this).val() + '; ';
                });                   
            }
        }
        $('.anchor').text(str);
    }); 
});
```

In fact, this code could further be optimized if desired!

Here's a fiddle demonstrating:

http://jsfiddle.net/74y6g/

Comment: thanks, but i wish to keep the functions the way they are. will you please help me figure out how to call the outputSelected function on my form?

Comment: this is the whole code, i didn't fail to mention anything. i just realized i didn't trigger my function with any event, but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: oh, nevermind, Jack - your code is indeed doing what i meant for it to do, thank you.